# Allowing the user to login once every 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is give user access to an application once every 24 hours.
Once they log out they have to wait another 24 hours before they can log in to.
But what I have notices is if it has been longer then an hour it works.
But if it has been less then an hour it still gives them access which I don't want to happen.
What can I do to fix this code?

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=127.0.01';
$user = 'USER';
$password = 'PASSWORD';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


function currentMysqlTime($dbh) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
    $sql->execute();
    $x = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $x[0][0];
}

 function lastLoginTime($dbh, $id) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM userpoints WHERE uid = ? AND pid = 2 ORDER BY timestamp desc LIMIT 1");
    $sql->execute(array($id));
    $y = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $y[0][3];
}
 function mysqlTimeDiff($dbh, $x, $y) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TIMEDIFF(?, ?)");
    $sql->execute(array($x, $y));
    $z = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $z[0][0];
}
    function daysSinceLastLogin($x) {
      $parts = explode(':',$x);
      return $parts[0];
}

$currentMysqlTime = currentMysqlTime($dbh);
$lastLoginTime = lastLoginTime($dbh, $id);

    $timeDiff = mysqlTimeDiff($dbh, $currentMysqlTime, $lastLoginTime);
    $daysSinceLastLogin = daysSinceLastLogin($timeDiff);

if($daysSinceLastLogin < 0) {
//NO ACCESS AS THE USER HAS ALREADY LOGGED IN

} else {
//GRANT ACCESS AS IT IS THERE FIRST TIME LOGGING IN TO THE APPLICATION
}
```

This is the output of the functions

Time of Registration 2011-09-16 07:10:04
Current Mysql Time 2011-09-17 05:41:22
Last Login Time 2011-09-14 05:00:07
Time Difference 72:41:15
Date Difference 3

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code?  For instance, have you confirmed that `mysqlTimeDiff` and `daysSinceLastLogin` are giving the correct results?

Comment: Like @Oli says, this calls for proper debugging first. When you know *where* exactly the problem is, come again and ask about *that*

Comment: Yes mysqlTimeDiff is using a mysql function that compares the time difference of two dates and returns them in HH:MM:SS,

Days since login takes that format and explodes the string so I can divide the hours by 24 to see how many days since the last login time.

Comment: But you're not dividing by 24, so you're checking the *hour* since last log in!

Comment: @Matthew: You need to e.g. add some `echo` statements (or step through in a debugger) to find out what the specific inputs and outputs of your functions are when things fail to work.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I've added the output of the functions to the quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code below will give you a boolean you can use to determine the authorization to log in.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('-24 hours', currentMysqlTime($dbh)); 
$allowedToLogin = (bool) $dbh->fetchOne('SELECT 1 FROM  * FROM userpoints WHERE uid = ? AND timestamp <= ?', array($uid, $timestamp)); // Assuming ZF syntax here
```

If there is a match for a timestamp inferior to the reference, you're good to go for a login by verifying the boolean `$allowedToLogin`.

Comment: +1 a clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

For your use, you probably want to use `DATEDIFF` instead of `TIMEDIFF`.  You're currently checking how many hours it is since the user logged in, not how many days.

Also, this code

```
if($daysSinceLastLogin < 0) {
```

is wrong - for one thing, you're taking a string "-00:12:34.123456", then taking the first part of that - "-00".  Then you're converting it to an integer.  Since there's no expression for negative zero as an integer, you just get 0, so your condition is never true in this context.

The other reason that it's wrong is that you want to be checking if it's less than 1 (hour), not less than 0 days.